# Assetic Dump error : facebook cURL

Tags: php, facebook, symfony, assetic

I am running Symfony2, and have installed the FOSFacebookBundle for handling facebook connectivity. But after installing this bundle, I am not able to do

```
`assetic:dump` OR `cache:clear`
```

anymore, because this error is thrown up:

```
[Exception]
Facebook needs the CURL PHP extension.
```

I have checked, and the cURL extension is installed in my PHP (its in the .ini file, and the facebook connectivity also works on my website, but this error still shows up in the console when I try to run the above mentioned commands)

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Php in console and your web  server use different php configurations. Use `-c` flag to 
specify the php config file or just create/edit php.ini in `php` bin folder:

```
php -c "/path/to/php.ini" app/console
```

Comment: actually, i did not have the php5-curl extension which was causing the problem. Thanks meze